# sed + cut words before the first “END” word in line

Tags: sed

How to cut words before the first “END” word in line, and not include the first character before the “END” word ( in our examples the character is “-“)

Only with sed command

For example:

```
  echo AAA-BBB-CCC-END | sed ...
  AAA-BBB-CCC


  echo 1-END-3-4 | sed ...
  1     


  echo 1-2-END-3-4 | sed ...
  1-2


  echo PARAM1-PARAM2-END | sed ...
  PARAM1-PARAM2


  echo fileExample1-fileExample2-END | sed ...
  fileExample1-fileExample2


  echo xyz_123-END | sed ...
  xyz_123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed "s/.END.*//"
```

This should do the trick.

It'll remove the first char before the END, and all chars after (and of course the END itself).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r "s/(.*).END.*/\1/"
```

would be my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

if your string structure always have hyphens and then the "END" word (eg -END),

```
$ var="AAA-BBB-CCC-SEND-END"
$ echo ${var%%-END*}
AAA-BBB-CCC-SEND
```

As you can see, in case you have words like "SEND", it will still give you the correct output.

if you still prefer using sed,

```
$ echo $var | sed 's/-END.*//'
AAA-BBB-CCC-SEND
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work: awkish not sedish, & literal

`awk '$0 !~ /(echo*|^$)/'`